# Sequelize went wrong when saved date in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to store an object to Mysql with Sequelize, Nodejs. Every things did ok, excepted the timestamp went wrong. There are my lines:

```
  var log = {
        id: id,
        error_code: error_code,
        created_at: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        updated_at: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
  }
  models.ErrorLog.create(log).then(function(log){
        console.log('Create Log');
        console.log(log);
  });
```

Focus on these two timestamp fields, I have logged and saw it was right when I created it.

```
var log = {
     created_at: '2016-11-16 22:51:24',
     updated_at: '2016-11-16 22:51:24'
}
```

But, It is wrong in the mysql record:

```
{
     created_at: '2016-11-17 05:45:34',
     updated_at: '2016-11-17 05:45:34'
}
```

In MySql, these fields are defined as:

```
- created_at: timestamp, nullable
- updated_at: timestamp, nullable
```

It is very basic, so I don't know what happened. It's so strange! 
Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is the time on the MySQL server set to? Sounds like a discrepancy in clocks/timezones.

Comment: Time in server Mysql had set correct timezone

Comment: Are you setting [`options.timezone` in Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/)? If you log all of the queries (`options.logging=console.log`) you can see the SQL that is being executed and try running it outside of Sequelize to see if it updates, that way you can determine if the issue is Sequelize or MySql.

Comment: your comment supposed be an answer. That works like a charm sir! thank you so much! plz move your comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Sequelize [`options.timezone`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#new-sequelizedatabase-usernamenull-passwordnull-options) property when creating your database connection to make sure that the application and MySQL server are both set to the same timezone offset.

> [options.timezone='+00:00']
>
> String
>
> The timezone used when converting a date from the database into a JavaScript date. The timezone is also used to SET TIMEZONE when connecting to the server, to ensure that the result of NOW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and other time related functions have in the right timezone. For best cross platform performance use the format +/-HH:MM. Will also accept string versions of timezones used by moment.js (e.g. 'America/Los_Angeles'); this is useful to capture daylight savings time changes.